# count letter in string without using count()

Tags: python

I am trying to do the function count without using count() it is working and everything okay but when I try to search two letters in one word its returning 0. When I try to search 1 word in a letter its working normal.

```
def count(str, sub):
    found = 0
    for key in str:
        if key == sub:
            found += 1
    return found

str = input("Enter a string: ") #or we can initialize a string
sub = input("Enter a substring: ") #or we can initialize a substring

count(str, sub)

print ("letter: ", sub)
print ("count: ", count(str, sub))
```

Comment: `for key in str:` will always go one letter at a time, so you can not use existing logic to search for two characters at a time.

Comment: your loop is searching for 1 letter at a time

Comment: @tbjorch i mean without doing ```print('bctestbc'.count('bc'))``` to return ```2```

Comment: @lllrnr101 yes now I realised that the for for loop will go one letter, any idea to turn into a word not letter by letter?

Comment: @VanshSachdeva yes now I realized, i am trying to find another method without letter by letter

Comment: Nerveless child's solution works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your method I suggest you do something like this:

```
def count(string, sub):
    found = 0
    size = len(sub)
    for i in range(len(string) + 1 - size):
        if string[i:i+size] == sub:
            found += 1
    return found
```

That way you can use it for any size of `sub`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def count(string, sub):
    found = 0

    for c in range(len(string)):
        start = c 
        end = -(len(string)-len(sub)-c) if -(len(string)-len(sub)-c) != 0 else None
        if string[start:end] == sub:
            found += 1
    return found

string = input("Enter a string: ") #or we can initialize a string
sub = input("Enter a substring: ") #or we can initialize a substring

print ("letter: ", sub)
print ("count: ", count(string, sub))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below should work for all length sub strings.

```
def count(str, sub):
    found = 0
    for i in range(1,len(str)+1): #iterate for all length substrings
        for j in range(len(str)-i+1): #iterate for different starting positions of substrings.
            key = str[j:j+i]
            if key == sub:
                found += 1
    return found
```

Comment: as you can see here that this method is not working for this letter [tested on programiz and uploaded on imgur](https://imgur.com/a/GqgGIIX)